# ¿Cómo puedo tener varias versiones de PHP en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, php7, windows, vscode, php5

Según la [Documentación oficial](https://docs.devsense.com/en/vscode/editor/php-version-select) parece simple, pero a mí no me sale esa opción en la esquina inferior derecha.

En mi settings.json tengo:

```
{
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp71\\php\\php.exe",
    "php.executablePath": "C:\\xampp71\\php\\php.exe",
    "php.executables": {
        "7.1":"C:\\xampp71\\php\\php.exe",
        "8.1":"C:\\xampp81\\php8\\php.exe"
    },
    "intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "8.1.*",
}
```

Lo cuál no me funciona! Si quito todo de este fichero de configuración y corro `php -v` obtengo:

```
PHP 8.1.17 (cli) (built: Mar 14 2023 23:07:43) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.17, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

En mis variables de entorno del sistema tengo:

```
C:\xampp81\php
C:\xampp71\php
```

Entiendo que si renombro los ficheros a php81.exe y la otra a php71.exe y luego los modifico en las variables de entorno funcionará en cmd, pero seguirá sin funcionar en VSC.

Comment: No puedes tener dos versiones de php en un mismo proyecto. Puedes tener todos los proyectos que quieras y en cada uno configurar versiones distintas para efectos de análisis estático, inferencia de tipos y linting. Por otro lado, Devsense está muy lejos de ser documentación oficial de nada. Sólo son los autores de algunos plugins para VSCode, pero si ya estás usando intelephense, quédate con él, no trabajará bien si poner otro plugin a hacer el mismo trabajo.

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo hacer para asignar una versión diferente para cada proyecto?

Comment: se permite definir el setting `"intelephense.environment.phpVersion"`  a nivel de proyecto. Aplica `CTRL+SHIFT+P` y busca por `workspace settings`. Hay otras utilidades, como [psalm](https://psalm.dev/)  que por defecto se basarán en lo que diga tu `composer.json`

Comment: O sea, existe un setttings a nivel global y luego otro a nivel de proyecto?

Comment: @ffflabs considero que si la respuesta es sobre una configuracion especifica de un plugin o herramienta de desarrollo utilizada para desarrollar, deberias colacarla como respuesta ... de mi parte es aceptable.

Comment: otra cosa si estas usando composer tambien puede definir en composer la version de php y en teoria el IDE puede sincronizarce con el archivo json de composer.

Comment: Cómo vinculo eso con las rutas de las versiones de PHP instaladas? ¿podrías detallarme más, por favor?

Comment: @Carlos el ejecutable que se configura a nivel de workspace (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php) no influye en lo que verás en la línea de comando. El terminal está fuera del control directo de VSCode